# Can a git commit have more than 2 parents?

Tags: git

In [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) it is mentioned

> A commit object may have any number of parents.

But from my understanding, the only case where a commit will have more than 1 parent is when a merge has happened, and in that case there will only be two parents. So my question is, can a commit have more than 2 parents? If so, when?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9b25d604182169a08b206306b312d2df26b5f502 - I don't think Github knows how to display a 27-way diff, but feel free to clone the repository and view it yourself.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use git merge to merge more than one commit into your current branch. From `man git-merge` (or `git help merge`):

> git-merge - Join two or more development histories together

The result will be a commit with more than two parents when you do that.

Comment: A merge of more than one branch (i.e. a commit with more than two parents) is colloquially known as an "octopus merge". That's also the source of inspiration for GitHub's logo and mascot, the eight-legged cat: it was originally called the Octopuss, but was renamed the more corporate-friendly Octocat.

Comment: "Couldn’t load network graph. Too many forks to display." _sob I want my sob forks I sob want my forks sob_

Comment: What are the advantages of merging three or more branches in a single commit, instead of a series of commits?

Comment: @TorKlingberg Cleaner history, but make sure to test the final product before pushing to the remote repsitory.

Comment: @DavidHammen can you please provide a sample link in github where there are more than 2 parent commits for a certain commit

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya - There are multiple examples in [one particular github repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). One of the many octopus merges in that repo which [involves 27 parents](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9b25d604182169a08b206306b312d2df26b5f502).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Literally none of that is true.

Source: worked at GitHub for five years.

Comment: @GJTorikian: the manual page for `git merge` says [**fat** emphasis mine] "Specifying more than one commit will create a merge with more than two parents (affectionately called an **Octopus merge**)." The command line option to select a merge strategy for more than two parents is called `octopus`. The executable that implements said merge strategy is called `git-merge-octopus`.

Comment: @JörgWMittagmate mate I was one hundred percent referring to the GitHub's logo and mascot and the "more corporate-friendly Octocat" part.

Comment: Insert "why would you do that?" meme here...

Comment: How can i revert such a commit

Comment: @AlexanderMladzhov - That's a new question, so ask it as a new question. A brief answer: `git revert` takes an optional `-m <parent-number>` argument. Quoting from the `git revert` man page, emphasis mine, "As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. **This may or may not be what you want**."

Answer (score 26):

**Yes, how about 100k parents?**

Here is a live GitHub example with a merge of 100k commits: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-octopus-100k Generated [with this script](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/blob/9374e5e18217982a13e354d2812d34a831ee3558/other-test-repos/many-commits-octopus.py).

**Trivia**

Linus does not like commits with more than 60 parents: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2017/the-biggest-and-weirdest-commits-in-linux-kernel-git-history

> It's pulled, and it's fine, but there's clearly a balance between "octopus merges are fine" and "Christ, that's not an octopus, that's a Cthulhu merge".

**Have a look at the format for the Git commit object**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968856/what-is-the-file-format-of-a-git-commit-object/37438460#37438460

From that analysis, we can see that the list of parents list is an arbitrary newline separated list of type:

```
parent {parent_1_sha}
parent {parent_2_sha}
...
parent {parent_N_sha}
```

and so an arbitrary number of parents is allowed.

**Minimal example**

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init

touch root
git add .
git commit -m root
sha_root="$(git log -1 --format="%H")"

touch 1
git add .
git commit -m 1
sha1="$(git log -1 --format="%H")"

git reset --hard "$sha_root"
touch 2
git add .
git commit -m 2
sha2="$(git log -1 --format="%H")"

git reset --hard "$sha_root"
touch 3
git add .
git commit -m 3
sha3="$(git log -1 --format="%H")"

git merge -m merge "$sha1" "$sha2"
```

View it:

```
git log --abbrev-commit --decorate --graph --pretty=oneline --all
```

Output:

```
*-.   70b4d8c (HEAD -> master) merge
|\ \  
| | * e54f235 2
| * | c7ab8ef 1
| |/  
* / ae5f932 3
|/  
* ef2f89e root
```

How it shows on git log:

```
commit 70b4d8c93b8ba47d3a2b2d4d45619ad5e0f34289 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: ae5f932 c7ab8ef e54f235
Author: Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 3 23:45:07 2020 +0000

    merge

commit ae5f932c1de34255400806f85f7f58ff52b7ae86
Author: Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 3 23:45:07 2020 +0000

    3

commit c7ab8efcb25e49ffc653ce5308cd5151d6a3fb94
Author: Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 3 23:45:07 2020 +0000

    1

commit e54f235a54da0900cec99301099673e3bc1cd01e
Author: Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 3 23:45:07 2020 +0000

    2

commit ef2f89eeb8fa83779b58b604f9814ec6fdfcc20c
Author: Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 3 23:45:07 2020 +0000

    root
```

so note how a commit with multiple parents gets the:

```
Merge: ae5f932 c7ab8ef e54f235
```

line with the parents. The parent of commits with a single parent is not as clearly shown in that format however, but we could get it with:

```
git log --pretty=raw
```

which gives:

```
commit 4210da20504fc08136421a351983c179baf0dccb
tree 2d509da01229d1c0f2f0efa0951fd623f6e26f62
parent 5b1eba2de78f303d5a3a8b0ca18fcf1219d5431a
parent 802c349017b0f911ccb8e59b1a730b51113d198d
parent 228b5883376dce7874c1c2269666077a9db285b6
author Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000
committer Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000

    merge

commit 5b1eba2de78f303d5a3a8b0ca18fcf1219d5431a
tree 235125b9eb17ab8889306536ca28a192cbb5499b
parent 1a257992f676efa966ffaf826e1bd1b6ece9325b
author Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000
committer Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000

    3

commit 802c349017b0f911ccb8e59b1a730b51113d198d
tree 64b425efe9e0a742c6a085eb4c0771641be57582
parent 1a257992f676efa966ffaf826e1bd1b6ece9325b
author Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000
committer Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000

    1

commit 228b5883376dce7874c1c2269666077a9db285b6
tree 40693988bf998a8acbc7cdec9982cdfd358915c9
parent 1a257992f676efa966ffaf826e1bd1b6ece9325b
author Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000
committer Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000

    2

commit 1a257992f676efa966ffaf826e1bd1b6ece9325b
tree f5ba07a8f892d043d1b8f3429d3bec69a2331d4b
author Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000
committer Ciro Santilli <ciro.santilli@gmail.com> 1642065317 +0000

    root
```

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059335/how-can-i-get-the-parents-of-a-merge-commit-in-git

Another related `git log` option is: `--min-parents` which filters commits by the number of parents.

Tested on git version 2.25.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if GitHub just can't handle a merge of that magnitude or if you've left it as a private repository. Or if GitHub is just having some unrelated issue. But regardless, the 100k merge link is a 500 error for me.

Comment: @8bittree it can't handle, private repo would be 400 :-) https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1344

Comment: What is this connection between bearded sandal wearing FOSS advocates and Lovecraft that I repeatedly enounter?

Answer (score 8):

You can specify more than one branch when merging.

For example:

```
git merge branch_A branch_B branch_C [...]
```

Then commit has more parents.